# How to get recent last 1 email from inbox with IMAP in PHP

Tags: php, imap

I want to get the recent last 1 email from inbox using IMAP in php. Please help me. I don't know how to get the last email from inbox. Please guide me with it. I will be thanks for your guideline.

Here is my code

```
              set_time_limit(4000); 

                // Connect to gmail
                    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}[Gmail]/All Mail';
                    $username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
                    $password = 'mypassword';
                    $keyword  = 'Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently';

                // try to connect 
                $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

                 $emails = imap_search($inbox,'BODY "'.$keyword.'"', SE_FREE, "UTF-8");
                $output = '';

                foreach($emails as $mail) {

                    $headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($inbox,$mail);

                    $output .= $headerInfo->subject.'<br/>';
                    $output .= $headerInfo->toaddress.'<br/>';
                    $output .= $headerInfo->date.'<br/>';
                    $output .= $headerInfo->fromaddress.'<br/>';
                    $output .= $headerInfo->reply_toaddress.'<br/>';

                    $emailStructure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$mail);

                    if(!isset($emailStructure->parts)) {
                         $output .= imap_body($inbox, $mail, FT_PEEK).'<br/></br/><br/>';

                    } else {
                        //    
                    }
                   echo $output;
                   $output = '';
                }
```

Comment: What is the issue / error you are facing?

Comment: I'm getting all the email which are match with keyword. But i want to get only last email with is match with keyword, not all email with match. I'm not facing with error but i want to get only one recent last email which is match with keyword. For example: In my Mail Inbox has 3 email which are include keyword message. I don't want to get all that mail. I only want to get only 1 mail from all of that which is the last recent time. Like 0 min ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`imap_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) function, there is no option to specify the number of entries that should be returned.

In your code, you are using

```
foreach($emails as $mail) {
```

The most simple solution here, would be only using the first element of the array, which would represent the most recent message meeting the search criteria.

```
$mail = $emails[0];
```

*edit*

I guess the array is in reverse order, so get the last element instead of the first - using [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php).

```
$mail = end($emails);
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Can u show me where to change in my code Please. I'm noob. Please

Comment: I did... Replace the loop, with the assignment. Instead of looping all emails in the array, only read the email at index 0.

Comment: Bro, It's show the first of the oldest mail. I want the recent last email bro. How can i fix it? Please help me.

Comment: Okay... then instead of using the first element of the array, use the last.

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer, to get the last element of the array.

Comment: How can i get that array bro?

Comment: Thanks alot bro. I will try it.

Comment: No worries, just be sure to upvote / accept the answers that help.

Comment: Yep bro. I'm Up. (y)